# Notification not displaying on android device. (Azure notification hub)

Tags: azure, push-notification, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I'm trying do send a push notification to my android emulator. When the notification is sent, it receives the notification but does not display it.

I'm using this code to display it.

```
void SendNotification(string messageBody)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                                                .SetContentTitle("FCM Message")
                                                                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                                                                .SetContentText(messageBody)
                                                                .SetChannelId("my-chanel")
                                                                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                                                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                                                .SetSound(); 

        var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);

        notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
```

But when the notification is received nothings happens and the logs of my devices gives me this:

```
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref ODEON.Android[0xa31db5c0] -> System.Core[0xa1f2f900]: 7
[MyFirebaseMsgService] From: 241571420247
[MyFirebaseMsgService] noti: 
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat[0xa31dca60] -> Java.Interop[0xa1f2f780]: 8
[Notification] Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
[Notification] See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
```

Can anyone tell my why it doesn't display. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the send notification mehtod is called use the below code to show notifications:

```
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
        .SetContentTitle("Title")
        .SetContentText(messageBody)
        .SetAutoCancel(true)
        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
    notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

Also if you have Android V 8+ devices which I'm sure you will see to it you are registering for a notification channel in your MainActivity OnCreate method

```
void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
            // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
            // channel on older versions of Android.
            return;
        }

        var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default)
                      {
                          Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
                      };

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager) GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

Comment: it says: CHANNEL_ID does not exist in current context

Comment: and im running on a nexus_galaxy (API 27) emulater

Comment: Channel id can be any string you want just see to it that when ever you need channel id you use the same something like this :`internal static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification_channel";`

Comment: It works (Y) but now i when i send a notification to my device i can't make dynamic content within the text. how do i e.g set the ContentText from a payload

Comment: You will have to check the docs for that and check [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/lb-lu/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm), [FCM single](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages) and [FCM multiple](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple) **Note** Its too much detail that I cannot add in the answer you will have to read all this.

Comment: oh okay thanks, now when i open the app i get these errors [InstanceID] No response
[FirebaseInstanceId] background sync failed: TIMEOUT, retry in 10s

Comment: Are you sure you are registered with firebase properly? Also you have an active internet connection in your device?

Comment: yes  because i got i working and i could send notifications. it helped to delete the emulater and then install it again. But it get's the same error after not being used for some time

Comment: okay, it retries for some times and then i suddenly comes through. and notifies

Comment: I would suggest you test this in real devices and not emulators as emulators do not have a consistent behavior

Comment: okay thank you i'll try that (Y) :) Thank you for the help, i'll mark this answer as the right one as you guided me with the right code and made the notify chanel for me aswell

Comment: Thanks in case you face any issues feel free to revert.